# Can't select 'public folder' and 'imported folder' with imap zimbra

Tags: python-3.x, email, imap, zimbra

A *'public folder'* is a folder that you share with someone, if anyone add an email in it you will recieve it too in this folder.

An *'imported folder'* is a folder that has been imported from another email account for example Gmail.

What i'm trying to do is just look at some mail on **zimbra** by using **imap** but when a folder is a public or imported one it does not work

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4(user['serv'], user['port'])
mail.login(user['name'], user['passwd'])
mail.select("INBOX") #which is an imported folder
```

> imaplib.IMAP4.error: SELECT command error: BAD [b'parse error: zero-length content']

The folder isn't empty but it seems that the contents has been hidden somehow

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4(user['serv'], user['port'])
mail.login(user['name'], user['passwd'])
mail.select("Shared mailbox") #which is a public folder
```

> imaplib.IMAP4.error: EXAMINE command error: BAD [b"parse error: wrong character; expected '(' but got 'd'"]

In the case of the 'public folder' it only happened when I'm not the one who created it, even with administrator right (right to add, delete email)

So I wanna know if anyone how to solve these issues

---

Edit:

I discovered another crash when the folder's name is not unidecode

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

And I don't know what encode is needed here so I tried 'ascii'

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

and I also tried 'utf-8'

> imaplib.IMAP4.error: SELECT command error: BAD [b'parse error: excess characters at end of command']

Comment: Folders with spaces need to be manually quoted: '"Shared mailbox"'.

Comment: Is there any way to do it not manually ?

Comment: No.  Use LIST to get the actual names of folders.  IMAP folders do not have non ASCII in them.  They are (modified) UTF-7 encoded.

Comment: You can always add quote marks if you wish, they don't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

`for i in mail.list()[1]:
    l = i.decode().split(' "/" ')
    if  l[1][1:len(l[1])-1] != "" and l[1][1:len(l[1])-1] not in banned:
       typ, data = mail.select('"{0}"'.format(l[1][1:len(l[1])-1]))`

That solved all the problem, dunno why we need to put the email's name between simple quote then double quote but it does work